# How to enable USB 3 for HP EliteBook Intel Core i7?

Tags: hp, usb-drive

I have two USB ports in my laptop (HP Intel Core i7) mode USB 2.
I need to have an USB 3. Is it possible to activate it, and how?

lsusb:

```
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub

Bus 001 Device 004: ID 04f2:b51d Chicony Electronics Co., Ltd 

Bus 001 Device 003: ID 138a:003f Validity Sensors, Inc. VFS495 Fingerprint Reader

Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:0a2b Intel Corp. 

Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Look in your BIOS for a USB setting that enables USB3 functionality.

Comment: i looked into the drivers file,the usb2 has a version 3.0 but when i connect a card to this port, it is recognized as version 2.0

Comment: I didn't tell you to look at driver files. I said that you need to look in your BIOS. Enter the BIOS at computer power up by hitting a special key like ESC, DEL, F2, or whatever your specific computer requires. Then look for a USB setting. And... to use USB3, you'll need a special USB3 cable and USB3 device, otherwise it'll operate at USB2 speed.

Comment: I look at the bios setting, i did'nt find any configuration of the USB ports that shows the version or speed.                                                                               I had a usb 3 cable and a card connected to it, but it is recognized as usb 2.   Is there any solution to make the usb port speed operate as version 3.            thank you in advance

Comment: What kind of a card are you trying to use? Does the USB3 port have blue ceramic in the center of the plug? Does the USB3 cable/card have blue ceramic in the center of the plugs?

Comment: The usb port of my laptop are not blue but the card cable is blue.                       it's an USRP B210 card.

Comment: If they're not blue, they are not USB3. There's no way to convert a USB2 port into a USB3 port.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

USB3 requires 4 things to operate at USB3 speeds:

1) USB3 **support** in your BIOS and Operating System

2) USB3 **ports** with blue ceramic in the center of the USB port

3) USB3 **cable** with blue ceramic in the center of the USB plug ends

4) USB3 **device** with blue ceramic in the center of the USB port

**Update**:

If your specific model # is 1040 G3, there's a recent BIOS update that you may wish to look into and install...

http://h20565.www2.hp.com/hpsc/swd/public/readIndex?sp4ts.oid=9789251&swLangOid=8&swEnvOid=4192

[image]
[image]

Comment: thank you for responding to my questions. 3 and 4 are ensured in my case, but the laptop port without the blue color doesn't mean that is not a version 3. I can't fix my problem

Comment: @oai_network What is the exact model # of your laptop?

Comment: HP EliteBook,  Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-6600U CPU @ 2.60GHz

Comment: You didn't give me the exact model #, so I had to guess that it's a 1040 G3. See my update to my answer. There's a BIOS update available from Jan 2017.

Comment: @oai_network  ps: Do the USB ports work at USB3 speed in Windows?

Comment: i am working on an ubunutu 14.04 at a partition besides the ubuntu 16

Comment: @oai_network did you see my update about your BIOS?